# Firebase & GTM in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, google-tag-manager

I'm facing problems with the integration of GTM in a FBase app.
Firebase works as it should i'm seeing events in debug mode in the firebaseconsole. The problem is I want to add GTM functionality..

I followed the steps on [the google documentation page](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/) , created the directory and added the json file. But it doesn't work.

[image: folder]
[image: dependencies]

Comment: I'm hoping Simo or Eike is picking this up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! I updated all the google dependencies to 11.0.4 and it started working. I tought the older version wouldn't be a problem since the GTM had been added already (i guess).